# Moving hint text in textview

Tags: android, material-design, textview

I notice in the hangouts app that the hint text in their TextView fields moves upward and reduces its size upon entry of the first character in the text fields.

When I specify hint text in a TextView, the hint text simply disappears upon entry in a text field.

Is the hangouts behavior using some a automatic feature of the TextView that I am not aware of, or are they just hard coding it?

Thanks,
Dean
EDIT: whoever labeled this as having been answered should consider the date of the answer.  Those posts were back in 2014 and libraries have changed since that time.

Comment: Sounds like it's using [`TextInputLayout`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/design/widget/TextInputLayout.html).

Comment: Why don't you just put that in an answer @MikeM. before someone takes the credit.

Comment: @Vucko I was looking for the duplicate I usually use for this. We really don't need this answered for the 10th time. :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Android floating labels were introduced in android design support library to display a floating label over EditText. Initially, it acts as a hint in EditText when the field is empty. When user starts inputting the text, it starts animating by moving to floating label position.

That is a good example you can see:

http://www.androidhive.info/2015/09/android-material-design-floating-labels-for-edittext/

Comment: This looks like a good article although I need to use an autocomplete instead of an edittext.  Thanks for the answer despite Mordac shutting off the thread!